# Angular 2/4 - Call PUT Method in a Asp Net WebApi gives Bad Request (400)

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api

I have a Angular 4 app that need to call an WebApi created in visual Studio (asp.net). 
The "get" method is Ok, I call and receive the expected response, but when I try to call the PUT or POST method, I always receives a BAD REQUEST (400) error.

**My Angular Service:**

```
 public AvisoLido(aviso:Aviso)  {

    let headers:Headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let options:RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({method:RequestMethod.Post, headers:headers})
    let obj = JSON.stringify(aviso.IdAviso);

    console.log(obj);
        let url = "http://localhost:11730/api/Home/"
        return this.http.post(
                url,
                obj,
                options 
        )

        .map((resposta:Response) => console.log(resposta.json()));

}
```

**CONTROLLER CODE:**

```
 [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class HomeController : ApiController
    {
        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public List<Aviso> GetAvisos(int idUsuario, string situacao)
        {
            AvisoBO bo = new AvisoBO();
            return bo.ListAvisoPorUsuario(idUsuario); 
        }


        [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]        
        public Aviso PostAviso([FromBody] Aviso obj)
        {
            return new Aviso();
        }
    }
```

**WebApiConfig:**

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new {action="*", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );


        config.EnableCors();
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);//);
```

I've tried to change the Angular Service, passing content type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  instead of Json format, and the controller method fires, but the parameter is always null in this case.

Anyone could help in this issue ?

Thanks a loT!

Comment: None of your actions accept a PUT request.  Why would you expect a PUT request to work?

Comment: You also havent shown us what the definition of `Aviso` is, nor have you shown us the actual raw PUT/POST.

Comment: Wrong attribute `[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]` Should be `[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]` similar to other requests like PUT/PATCH etc.

Comment: @12seconds good eye

Comment: I recommend change the title to POST, since you only showing us post method.

Comment: Post and Put give me the same error. In this case, I published here the post code. It's my first time in StackOverflow, how can I change the title ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
```

should be:

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
```

Mini generic example below

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public MyReturnObject PostAndReturnSomething([FromBody]MyInputObject args)
    {
           return null;
    }
```

Comment: Granada, I did the change but the error is the same..
"Failed to load http://localhost:11730/api/Home/: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400"

Comment: put a breakpoint on "return null;" (anywhere in side the server side method.  do you get there?  is "args" populated?  another tip, use PostMan to post raw json...remove angular from the equation temporarily.